# $F(a_1,\ldots,a_n) = F(a_1+t_2 a_n+\cdots+t_n a_n)$ if Extension is Simple?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Suppose that F is an infinite field and that $L = F(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ is a simple extension of $F$.

Can you show, without the assumption that $[L:F] < \infty$ that $\exists t_2,\ldots,t_n \in F$ such that $L = F(a_1+t_2 a_n+\cdots+t_n a_n)$?

With that assumption I would use the fact that, under these assumptions, there are a finite number of subfields, and find $\beta_1,\beta_2\in F$ s.t $F(a_1+\beta_1 a_2) = F(a_1+\beta_2 a_2)$ (since $F$ infinite), then conclude that $a_1,a_2 \in F(a_1 + \beta_1 a_2)$. From here proceed by induction on $n$.

Thanks!

Comment: The assumption $\;[L:F]<\infty\;$ doesn't necessarily mean there is a finite number of subfields: the extension $\;\Bbb F_p(X,Y)\;$ is of order $\;p^2\;$ over $\;\Bbb F_p(X^p,Y^p)\;,\;\;p\;$ a prime, yet there are infinite subextensions (and, of course, this extension isn't separable and thus not simple).